# Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0 error when I try to access through element.all in protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to getText for one of the elements having same class. But I'm getting Index out of bond error. Any help would be appreciated!

Below is the exact error :

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but
>   there are only 0 elements that match locator By(xpath,
>   //div[contains(@class,'partial className')])

Below is the snapshot of the code:

```
this.loginloc['CurrentProgrammeTitle'].isPresent().then(() => {
  this.loginloc['CurrentProgrammeTitle'].getText().then(currentTitle => {
    selectedChannelTitle = currentTitle;
    console.log('Current Title :' + selectedChannelTitle);
  });
  this.loginloc['NextProgrammeTitle'].getText().then(nextTitle => {
    nextChannelTitle = nextTitle;
    console.log('Next Title :' + nextChannelTitle);
  });
});
```

Comment: It means it is returning zero elements  and calling `.getText()` is failing as there are no elements to get text from.

Comment: Yes @RyanWilson, but not sure, the previous condition this.loginloc['CurrentProgrammeTitle'].isPresent() is being executed, and in the next statement returning zero elements

Comment: Then it is another portion of code which you are not showing that is the issue, more than likely somewhere that you try to get a div by xpath that contains class, partial className;

Comment: there can be many reasons for that. If I were you I would double check that the locator is right by pausing testing before failure and exploring document. Then there is a possibility that the element you're looking for is located inside iframe (a page inside of a page)

Answer (score 0):

Can you share code of loginloc[].

It is probable, number of elements returned from the array is 0 and you are trying to getText() on the 0th element in array which doesn't exist.

Also, it would be better to use below snippet:

```
this.loginloc['CurrentProgrammeTitle'].isPresent().then((output) => {
  if(output){ //checking if the element is present, then trying to execute next steps
   // do other work here
  }
});
```

Comment: Here I have locators in loginloc and below is the xpath I'm using, CurrentProgrammeTitle: element.all(by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'type_LiveInfoTitle')]")).first(),

Comment: Please check your location once again, I believe it is wrong.

Comment: Also, unless you are checking output of isPresent() is true or false, you shouldn't be writing getText() on it. Unless you are sure it is visible.